# GroupBy Array elements from CSV file and help reduce code

Tags: javascript, node.js

Each csv file that is imported has the same data structure.
I need to **sum** the ['Net Charge Amount'] by each '[Service Type'].
I am currently doing this by assigning each unique ['Service Type'] to their own array. My current script is probably overkill but it is very easy to follow, however I am looking for a more compact way of doing this otherwise this script could get very long.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const { parse } = require('csv-parse')

// Arrays for each service type
const GroundShipments = []
const HomeDeliveryShipments = []
const SmartPostShipments = []
const Shipments = []
```

The **[Shipments]** array will hold all data and I would assume this is the array
we want to work with

```
//functions for each service type
function isGround(shipment) {
 return shipment['Service Type'] === 'Ground'
}
   
function isHomeDelivery(data) {
 return data['Service Type'] === 'Home Delivery'
}
function isSmartpost(shipment) {
    return shipment['Service Type'] === 'SmartPost'
}
function isShipment(shipment) {
    return shipment['Service Type'] === 'Ground' || shipment['Service Type'] === 'Home Delivery' ||
    shipment['Service Type'] === 'SmartPost'
}
// Import csv file / perform business rules by service type
// output sum total by each service type
fs.createReadStream('repco.csv')
    .pipe(parse({
        columns: true
    }))
    .on('data', (data) => {
        //push data to proper service type array
        // Ground
         if (isGround(data)) {
            GroundShipments.push(data)
            }
        // Home Delivery
        if (isHomeDelivery(data)) {
            HomeDeliveryShipments.push(data)
            }
        // Smartpost
        if (isSmartpost(data)) {
            SmartPostShipments.push(data)
            }
        // All shipment types, including Ground, Home Delivery, and Smartpost
        if (isShipment(data)) {
            Shipments.push(data)
        }    
    })
    .on('error', (err) => {
        console.log(err)
    })
    .on('end', (data) => {
        // sum data by service type
        // Ground Only
        const sumGround = GroundShipments.reduce((acc, data) =>
        acc + parseFloat(data['Net Charge Amount']), 0)
        // Home Delivery Only
        const sumHomeDelivery = HomeDeliveryShipments.reduce((acc, data) =>
        acc + parseFloat(data['Net Charge Amount']), 0)
        // SmartPost Only
        const sumSmartPost = SmartPostShipments.reduce((acc, data) =>
        acc + parseFloat(data['Net Charge Amount']), 0)
        // All services
        const sumAllShipments = Shipments.reduce((acc, data) => 
        acc + parseFloat(data['Net Charge Amount']), 0)
      
        //output sum by service type to console
        console.log(`${GroundShipments.length} Ground shipments: ${sumGround}`)
        console.log(`${HomeDeliveryShipments.length} Home Delivery shipments: ${sumHomeDelivery}`)
        console.log(`${SmartPostShipments.length} Smartpost shipments: ${sumSmartPost}`)
        console.log(`${Shipments.length} All shipments: ${sumAllShipments}`)
    })
```

Here is the console output:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FltTU.png

Instead of separating each ['Service Type'] by its own Array and Function, I would like one Array **[Shipments]** to output each unique ['Service Type'] and sum total of ['Net Charge Amount']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution would be to use a `Map` instance to keep track of the stats of different service types.

For each `shipment` find the associated `stats` (based on service type), or create a new stats object `{ count: 0, sum: 0 }`. Then increment the count, and add the amount to the sum.

When all data is iterated (on end), you can loop through the `serviceTypeStats` which and log the values. You can also use this loop to calculate the total by adding all `count` and `sum` of each service type group.

```
const serviceTypeStats = new Map();

// ...
.on('data', (shipment) => {
  const serviceType = shipment['Service Type'];
  const amount      = parseFloat(shipment['Net Charge Amount']);

  if (!serviceTypeStats.has(serviceType)) {
    serviceTypeStats.set(serviceType, { count: 0, sum: 0 });
  }

  const stats = serviceTypeStats.get(serviceType);

  stats.count += 1;
  stats.sum   += amount;
})
// ...
.on('end', () => {
  const total = { count: 0, sum: 0 };
  for (const [serviceType, stats] of serviceTypeStats) {
    total.count += stats.count;
    total.sum   += stats.sum;

    console.log(`${stats.count} ${shipmentType}: ${stats.sum}`);
  }

  console.log(`${total.count} All shipments: ${total.sum}`);
})
```

If you want to loop keys in a specific order you can define the order in an array, or sort the keys of the Map instance.

```
// pre-defined order
const serviceTypeOrder = ["Ground", "Home Delivery", "SmartPost"];
// or
// alphabetic order (case insensitive)
const serviceTypeOrder = Array.from(serviceTypeStats.keys());
serviceTypeOrder.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b, undefined, { sensitivity: "base" }));

// ...
for (const serviceType of sericeTypeOrder) {
  const stats = serviceTypeStats.get(serviceType);
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and example! I really like the idea of using the Map instance, especially because it can be assigned a variable and an object to the same instance, like you've demonstrated. This might be old hat for some, but because I am fairly new to Javascript, it's pretty cool. My customers will appreciate seeing the snapshot of this data. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

The two keys to simplifying this are:

1. separating the CSV parsing from the data processing
2. using a `groupBy` function

First, you should parse the CSV into a simple JS array. Then you can use regular JS utility functions to operate on the data, such as the `groupBy` function. It is a utility that can be found in the lodash and ramda libraries. It's probably going to be added to vanilla JS as the `.group` method but that's a while from now.

I was looking for a sample problem to play with my own JS evaluation framework, so I answered your question there:

[image: screenshot of solution in val.town]

You can explore the underlying val yourself: https://www.val.town/stevekrouse.exampleGroupByShppingCSV

There are a couple things about my answer that wouldn't make sense in a normal NodeJS codebase, but that I had to do to make it work in val.town (async/await, using a custom groupBy method instead of importing one). If you'd like help getting it to work in your application, just let me know.

Comment: Steve, thank you for showing another way to solve this. I am having a little trouble figuring out where the data is getting populated from your example, as opposed to the fs.createReadStream I am using in Node. Regardless, I can still learn by your provided example. Thank you.

Comment: My pleasure! Made a little video reply for you: https://www.loom.com/share/eb6080b979894b54baeb06dc865c8312